# Turning Resharper on/off

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

Can I switch resharper on/off in a simple manner.
The issue is sometimes I dealing with big files  and makes my VS slow, sometimes it pops out a message telling me resharper is out of memory. Can I activate/deactivate it without having to reload the solution?

Comment: Duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253063/disable-but-not-uninstall-resharper-4-x

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I disable ReSharper in Visual Studio and enable it again?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189792/how-can-i-disable-resharper-in-visual-studio-and-enable-it-again)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> on the big files:

http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeffrey.palermo/archive/2007/11/28/temporarily-disable-code-analysis-for-single-code-file-with-resharper-3-0-2-and-vs-2008.aspx

Answer (score 22):

In versions **7.0-2017** it's in

```
Tools > Options > ReSharper > Suspend
```

Answer (score 9):

In ReSharper 5.0, the keyboard shortcut to temporarily enable/disable code analysis for the current file is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>. It was <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> in previous versions.

Comment: Thanks so much for this.  I had a devilish time finding this in JetBrains' documentation.

Comment: Refer to [this](https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206546999-How-can-I-temporary-disable-turn-off-ReSharper-) resharper page for additional information on configuring the shortcut

Answer (score 0):

[Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>](http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2008/08/06/how-to-disable-resharper-for-a-file-ctrl-8.aspx).

Alternatively, [click Tools, Add-in Manager, and uncheck ReSharper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253063/disable-but-not-uninstall-resharper-4-x/253167#253167).