# How can I disable ReSharper in Visual Studio and enable it again?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, resharper

I installed [ReSharper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReSharper), and it works in Visual Studio, but how can I disable it?

Whenever I search in the ReSharper menu, I can't find a disable option.

Comment: The `suspend option` by @matthew.perron works for me, but I also lost all the built-in code-analysis/inspection of Visual Studio :(

Answer (score 539):

You can disable ReSharper 5 and newer versions by using the <kbd>Suspend Now</kbd> button in menu *Tools* → *Options* → *ReSharper*.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  It's sad but I have to disable every time i'm working html and .aspx pages.

Comment: I found I need to disable it for TypeScript -- it just gets everything wrong.

Answer (score 157):

If you want to do it without clicking too much, open the Command Window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>) and type:

`ReSharper_Suspend` or `ReSharper_Resume` depending on what you want.

Or you can even set a keyboard shortcut for this purpose. In Visual Studio, go to *Tools* -> *Options* -> *Environment* -> *Keyboard*.

There you can assign a keyboard shortcut to `ReSharper_Suspend` and `ReSharper_Resume`.

The Command Window can also be opened with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, just in case you're in the editor.

[image]

Comment: `Command Window` for me is bound to `Ctrl` `alt` `A`. That might be because Re# has bound the `Ctrl` `W` to `Extend selection`

Comment: Any option to disable it completely. It conflicts with keyboard. I don't want to do any changes with ReSharper - just disable, not suspend. Suspend keeps the shortcut to itself!

Comment: As also mentioned in other answers: there is also a hotkey called ReSharper_ToggleSuspended which allows you to use one HotKey to switch between suspended and resume.

Answer (score 78):

Bind `ReSharper_ToggleSuspended` to a shortcut key.

Steps:

1. Tools>Options
2. Click Keyboard on the left hand side
3. Type "suspend" in the "Show commands containing:" input box
4. Pick the "ReSharper_ToggleSuspended"
5. Press shortcut keys: and
6. Press the "Assign" button.

Binding `ReSharper_ToggleSuspended` to a shortcut key (in my case: Ctrl-Shift-Q) works very well.  With ReSharper not supporting the async CTP yet (as of mid-2011), when dipping into the code the uses the async keyword, this shortcut is invaluable.

Comment: I find this the most practical of the solutions posted for temporarily suspending ReSharper (and it's easy to see the current state by the presence/absence of the ReSharper menu bar entry).  One notable case is when switching solution configurations for reasonably large (> 50 project) solutions.  This operations is approx 10x slower with ReSharper enabled (252 seconds vs. 25 seconds without).  It is very handy to be able to toggle ReSharper off temporarily for tweaking project settings, then re-enable, without requiring reloading or option menu drilling.

Comment: I like this toggling option. Sometimes, when I type re# slows me down big time. I thought disabling would help me type faster. But when I enabled it back it takes so long to load that ultimately it slows me down even more :( now I'm learning to live with slow typing :(

Answer (score 49):

I always forget how to do this and this is the top result on Google.  IMO, none of the answers here are satisfactory.
So the next time I search this and to help others, here's how to do it and what the button looks like to toggle it:

[image: Toggle Resharper Toolbar Button]

- Make sure Resharper is currently enabled or the commands may fail.
- Open `package manager console` via the `Quick Launch` bar near the caption buttons to launch a PowerShell instance.
- Enter the code below into the Package Manager Console Powershell instance:

If you want to add it to the standard toolbar:

```bsh
$cmdBar = $dte.CommandBars.Item("Standard") 
$cmd = $dte.Commands.Item("ReSharper_ToggleSuspended")
$ctrl = $cmd.AddControl($cmdBar, $cmdBar.Controls.Count+1)
$ctrl.Caption = "R#"
```

If you want to add it to a new custom toolbar:

```bsh
$toolbarType = [EnvDTE.vsCommandBarType]::vsCommandBarTypeToolbar
$cmdBar = $dte.Commands.AddCommandBar("Resharper", $toolbarType)
$cmd = $dte.Commands.Item("ReSharper_ToggleSuspended")
$ctrl = $cmd.AddControl($cmdBar, $cmdBar.Controls.Count+1)
$ctrl.Caption = "R#"
```

If you mess up and need to start over, remove it with:

```bsh
$ctrl.Delete($cmdBar)
$dte.Commands.RemoveCommandBar($cmdBar)
```

In addition to adding the button, you may wish to add the keyboard shortcut
`ctrl+shift+Num -, ctrl+shift+Num -` that is: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>

EDIT:
Looks like StingyJack found the original post I found long ago. It never shows up when I do a google search for this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41792417/16391

Comment: I can never find the post without tooling around for several minutes either, so I added it to a bunch of posh scripts that I can find https://github.com/StingyJack/Vs-Utility/blob/master/Add-ResharperToggleButton.ps1

Comment: Best solution IMO

Comment: Best solution, but be aware that at least the first command group will fail if r# is currently not enabled!

Comment: This one of the greatest answer ever, not only for this question, but in general. No talk, just code, and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 29):

If resharper is completely missing from the options menu, it could be because the extension itself has been disabled.

In Visual Studio 2017 ReSharper 2018.X.X can be enabled and disabled by going to `Help` > `Manage Visual Studio Performance`. Then select `JetBrains ReSharper ...` under `Extensions`.

[image]

In Visual Studio 2019, you would go under `Extensions->Manage Extensions->Installed`

Answer (score 12):

You can add a menu item to toggle ReSharper if you don't want to use the command window or a shortcut key. Sadly the `ReSharper_ToggleSuspended` command can't be directly added to a menu (there's an [open issue on that](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-303216)), but it's easy enough to work around:

Create a macro like this:

```
Sub ToggleResharper()

    DTE.ExecuteCommand("ReSharper_ToggleSuspended")

End Sub
```

Then add a menu item to run that macro:

1. Tools | Customize...
2. Choose the Commands tab
3. Choose the menu you want to put the item on
4. Click Add Command...
5. In the list on the left, choose "Macros"
6. In the resulting list on the right, choose the macro
7. Click OK
8. Highlight your new command in the list and click Modify Selection... to set the menu item text etc.

Comment: How to add a macro in VS2017?

Comment: @HrvojeHudo Macros don't exist anymore in VS2017.

Answer (score 12):

You need to goto Tools-->Options--->Select Resharper--->Click on suspend now,to disable it

Answer (score 10):

In case the solution did not help to just suspend resharper (STRG+R, STRG+R did still not work for example) I decided to disable the plugin and restart visual studio.

```
VisualStudio > Extras > Extensions > Resharper > Disable
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/how-to-diagnose-extension-performance
[image]

Answer (score 10):

Now Resharper supports Suspend & Resume argument at devenv.exe

(ReSharper 2019.2.3)

Run VS & Suspend R#:

```
devenv.exe /ReSharper.Suspend
```

Run VS & Resume R#:

```
devenv.exe /ReSharper.Resume
```

Here's an example usage:

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, and can confirm that it works VS2019 and Resharper 2020.X!
Thank you!

Now, I just need to know how to enable/disable xaml designer via commandline as well.

Answer (score 7):

In ReSharper 8:
Tools -> Options -> ReSharper -> Suspend Now

Answer (score 7):

For ReSharper 2017.2.2, go to ReSharper | Options | Product and features.
[image]

Comment: It still works via Tools -> Options -> ReSharper (VS2015, ReSpharper 2017.2.2), which is where you have to go to if you want to enable it again. (ReSpharper->options-> Product and features won't be available after ReSharper has been disabled)

Answer (score 6):

Tools -> Options -> ReSharper (Tick "Show All setting" if ReSharper option not available ). Then you can do Suspend or Resume. Hope it helps (I tested only in VS2005)

Answer (score 5):

Very simple steps:

1. Go to Extensions → Manage Extensions
2. Click on Installed section at the top left and search for "resharper"

You will see **disable** button over the extension, click to it then restart **Visual Studio** and that's it!

[image]

Comment: Precisely, you may be looking for Resharper... but look for JetBrains, that is how you can reenable it if you suspended it and can't find it again... It is also how you can disable it instead of suspending it.