# Ctrl-W stopped working

Tags: resharper

I have Resharper installed and somehow <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> no longer "extends the selection".  I tried assigning it to Global / Resharper.ExtendSelection in Tools -> Options -> Keyboard but it still only selects one word.

Answer (score 13):

I have found the resolutions. Go to ReSharper -> Options -> Visual Studio Integration -> Keybord Shortcuts --> ReSharper or IntelliJ IDEA.Next time when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>W</kbd>, Visual studio will ask you about shortcuts. You will choice ReSharper shortcuts and that is it.

Comment: Where can I find this in Resharper 2017.1.2?

Answer (score 6):

A solution i found was to reconfigure keys at the `Text Editor` level (they are defined at `Global` level and for some (annoying) reason Resharper overrides this.

So: `(Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboard)`, set `Use new shortcut` to `Text Editor` and redefine your shortcuts.

Tip: Look for your <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> favorites by writing `view.` at `Show commands containing`. 
I needed View.ErrorList (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>), View.Output (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>O</kbd>) & View.SolutionExplorer (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>)

HTH

p.s.
I even disabled [Resharper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189792/how-can-i-disable-resharper-in-vs-and-enable-it-again) and it still won't work...

Comment: I was actually trying to figure out the opposite.  Ctrl-w stopped closing the current document...  I overrode it at the global level, but resharper had stolen it in "Text Editor".  This has been driving me nuts for *weeks*.  Thank you!

Comment: ReSharper.Resharper_ExtendSelection and ReSharper.Resharper_ShrinkSelection  are the command that worked for me

Answer (score 5):

A question and a suggestion:

- Does Resharper | Edit | Extend Selection work?
- Reapply VS integration via Resharper | Options | Visual Studio Integration | Apply Scheme

Comment: Interesting... Extend Selection is disabled!

Comment: Possibly it's your source file doesn't support Extend Selection? I believe HTML and javascript don't support it. Is it available in a C#/VB file?

Comment: This worked for me.

Extend Selection work is now CTRL + Alt + Left or Right Arrow keys in 2017.3.2

Answer (score 2):

For me the reason was a silly one:

My C# file was removed from the project accidentally, so resharper no longer regarded it as C# code and so there were no syntactical elements to extend the selection to. In other files it worked ok.

Answer (score 2):

In my case (Visual 2019)

1. go to Tools\Options\Environment\Keyboard
2. set  **Apply the following additional keyboard mapping scheme** to **Resharper (Visual Studio)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the silliest reason.
after the resharper installation I didn't apply my license or started the evaluation.