# Analyzing Code Coverage on code using Fakes fail during TFS build

Tags: code-coverage, tfsbuild, microsoft-fakes

I am having some problems after enabling Code Coverage during our TFS builds. The solution under test contain three test projects and out of 209 tests three tests fail (one in one project and two in another), with the following error:

```
Test method MyNamespace.MyTest threw exception: 
Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.UnitTestIsolation.UnitTestIsolationException: Unexpected error returned by SetDetourProvider in profiler library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\IntelliTrace\14.0.0\Microsoft.IntelliTrace.Profiler.14.0.0.dll'.
Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.UnitTestIsolation.IntelliTraceInstrumentationProvider.Initialize()
Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.UnitTestIsolation.UnitTestIsolationRuntime.InitializeUnitTestIsolationInstrumentationProvider()
Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.Shims.ShimRuntime.CreateContext()
Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.ShimsContext.Create()
MyNamespace.MyTest () in MyFile.cs: line 224
```

The stack trace indicates that is connected to the use of Shims. All test pass locally even when running Code Coverage and disabling Code Coverage during build makes the tests pass again.
The issue seems slightly related to [Microsoft Fakes generates UnitTestIsolationException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20686805/microsoft-fakes-generates-unittestisolationexception), but Resharper is not installed on the build servers.

**What I have tried**:

1. Different build types: Build vNext, XAML Build with customized or Default Template
2. Explicitly disabled IntelliTrace using `/p:EnableIntelliTrace=true` and .runsetting
3. Added `Diagnostic="true"` to all .fakes files
4. Increased Logging Verbosity to get more error information
5. Run the tests locally on the server through command line

**My build server setup**:

- Windows Server 2012 R2
- Team Foundation Server 2015.3
- Visual Studio Enterprise 2015.3

Comment: Try to go to your build agent machine, launch the Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt, and run: vstest.console.exe MyTestAssembly.dll /EnableCodeCoverage to see what result will you get.

Comment: @Cece-MSFT: I am getting the same error. I do however get different number of failed tests dependent on order of the three test assemblies in the command. I get 3 failed tests if I run the same order as the server chooses or just one error I choose another order.

Comment: As you mentioned you could get number of tests, did it mean you can get Code Coverage now? Did you use default build process template? Could you describe your project, I'd like to have a test on my side.

Comment: @Cece-MSFT: I get different numbers of tests failing, depending on the order of test assemblies, but I get Code Coverage results every time. I see now that the title of my question is wrong - I will update this. We are running with a customized process template, but I believe that the test/codecoverage part is standard. The tests are calling ShimsContext.Create() and overriding two functions to return a hardcoded value in some cases. I will try to make a minimal setup that triggers the problem.

Comment: I see the same issue when changing to the default build template.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with the same error message, though in my case it was when running the tests themselves.  When executed from the commandline, vstest.console.exe worked flawlessly, but when run from a Bamboo build task, it failed with the message above.

The problem was ultimately the user running the task - the build server used the SYSTEM user.  When I  ran the task as a normal privilege user, it succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

According to Feedbacks [UnitTestIsolationException when debugging tests using Fakes with IntelliTrace Enabled](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/886864/unittestisolationexception-when-debugging-tests-using-fakes-with-intellitrace-enabled) and [Debugging a c# Unit Test with fakes and Intellitrace turned on throws UnitTestIsolationException](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1821885/debugging-a-c-unit-test-with-fakes-and-intellitrace-turned-on-throws-unittestisolationexception), Fakes does not work if intellitrace is enabled in test setting.

Comment: But we are not using Intellitrace and we have lots of test using Fakes that work just fine with Code Coverage...

Comment: And the tests are run in release mode.

Comment: @ToreØstergaard, your error message points to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\IntelliTrace\14.0.0\Microsoft.IntelliTrace.Profiler.14.0.0.dll, you may need double check it.

Comment: I have checked that file and it exists on the five servers that are running the tests. I have also tried to actively disable IntelliTrace by adding "/p:EnableIntelliTrace=true" to the MSBuild Arguments.