# ReSharper silently refuses to run NUnit tests

Tags: c#, nunit, resharper

I have the following:

```
namespace repro
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class repro
    {
        [Test]
        public void nunit_works()
        {
            Assert.That(true, Is.True);
        }
    }
}
```

When I attempt to run the test via ReSharper 10, Resharper quietly refuses to run the test (displayed as "inconclusive"):

[image]

This holds in VS2012 and VS2015.  I've tried starting from a fresh checkout of the project and all of the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613661/resharper-unit-tests-not-running) (except for repaving my system).  In particular, neither clearing Resharper's cache nor forcing the tests to be run in a 32bit process has any effect on the outcome.

*EDIT:* Setting a breakpoint at the start of the test reproduces the "debugger fires up then immediately exits" behaviour described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613661/resharper-unit-tests-not-running).

*EDIT 2:* Uninstalling, then reinstalling ReSharper doesn't fix it either.

Any ideas?

Comment: ReSharper 10 crapped out tlit's entire unit test runner. A hotfix should be deployed next week under 10.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalling R# 10 and reverting to R# 9.3 seems to have done the trick.

(Really the solution is to avoid working on projects with harrowing and obscure pre-build dependencies and use NCrunch, but that's not what I'm getting paid to do.)