# How can I temporary disable/turn off ReSharper 2016?

Tags: c#, resharper

In the old version I can use *Suspend* button. But now I can't find the button.

Comment: Have you tried the following instructions from this link? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189792/how-can-i-disable-resharper-in-visual-studio-and-enable-it-again

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I disable ReSharper in Visual Studio and enable it again?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189792/how-can-i-disable-resharper-in-visual-studio-and-enable-it-again)

Answer (score 2):

Now it is in Visual Studio Options window on Resharper Ultimate General tab.