# Visual studio 2017 showing Errors for Blazor but compiles

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, resharper, blazor

EDIT:
Found issue to be resharper. When I disable it it stop showing errors.

When I start a new Blazor fullstack project from Visual Studio it shows error in IDE. I have looked at [Visual Studio displaying errors even if projects build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17703004/visual-studio-displaying-errors-even-if-projects-build) but doesn't seem to help.

I followed the guide on Blazor (https://blazor.net/docs/get-started.html)

But the client side project shows lots of errors

EG:
[image]

and more details:
[image]

and:
[image]

[image]

Any one else tried this and know how to fix it?

I am running VS Studio Enterprise 2017 Version 15.8.8
I have installed ASP.NET Core Blazor Language Services.

Everything seems to work as it should. I was able to add new page with external RestAPI calls and all.

Edit:
Updated VS to latests version with no luck

Seems it might be resharper:
https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000554550-ASP-NET-Core-Razor-Pages-page-Cannot-resolve-symbol-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. Seems that jetbrains is aware of issue.
It can be found here:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-469186

Not much to do than disable Resharper for the moment and wait for them to fix it :)

If you need help to disable and enable it again:
[How can I disable ReSharper in Visual Studio and enable it again?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189792/how-can-i-disable-resharper-in-visual-studio-and-enable-it-again)

Comment: The latest ReSharper mostly works fine with Blazor.  Are you sure you're on the *preview* version VS 2017?  (that's a listed requirement)

Comment: I assume you're not on the preview version of VS2017.  Interesting -- apparently it's no longer required for Blazor (this would be a pretty recent change).  I wonder if ReSharper is not supporting Blazor when not using the preview.

Comment: So I've tested between the latest VS2017 and the preview edition and the problem is not present when using the preview edition.  So my hunch is that resharper is not ready yet for the latest version of the non-preview edition that now supports Blazor.