# Is It possible to start VS 2008 without resharper?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, resharper

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disable, but not uninstall Resharper 4.x onwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253063/disable-but-not-uninstall-resharper-4-x-onwards)

i have a full licensed version of resharper on my VS2008 but sometime i need to start VS without it, there is a way to do so without uninstalling ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a varient you can suspend resharper. Type in command window "ReSharper_Suspend"

Answer (score 2):

You can run the Visual Studio in safe mode, using the [`/SafeMode` switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) from the command line:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /SafeMode
```

This will disable all third-party packages and add-ons, and prevent them from loading.

If you find yourself needing to do this frequently, you can even create a new shortcut and add this switch to the target path so that double-clicking that shortcut automatically opens Visual Studio in safe mode.

Comment: this was quite cool, but still i prefere the "CTRL+W,A" Resharper_suspend foud here:  :D http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253063/disable-but-not-uninstall-resharper-4-x-onwards

Answer (score 2):

http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/Suspend+ReSharper+5+in+Visual+Studio