# Issue with reference .net core class library to project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I created new asp.net core WebApplication and .net core class library.
Then I tried to add a reference to .net core class library from asp.net core.
It built ok, but it is not visible.

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Is your Resharper up-to-date?

Comment: I've updated it to Ultimate 2016.1.2 and it gives the advice to add  the reference but it doesn't help and reference has been added already.

It's weird but if I rerun visual studio it'll be visible for a moment and then not visible again.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you on, looks like you still have `VS 2015 Update 1`, but you will need `Update 2`.

Comment: I have VS 2015 update 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Any idea?

Yes, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9799074/how-to-make-resharper-re-evaluate-its-assembly-reference-highlighting) can sometimes be related to **ReSharper's** cache.

*Follow these steps:*

1. `Build > Clean Solution`
2. `Resharper > Options> General > "Clear Cache"`
3. `Restart Visual Studio`
4. `Build > Rebuild Solution`