# Issue referencing a .Net Core Class project from a .Net Core Console Application

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am quite new to .Net Core and I am having an issue when trying to reference a .Net Core Class Assembly Project from my .Net Core Console Application.
It is a very similar issue to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37419018/issue-with-reference-net-core-class-library-to-project), however the answers here did not help me.

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3

I am using ReSharper Ultimate 2016.1.2

I am using .Net Core 1.0.0 Preview 2 (RC2)

### .Net Core Class project

#### Class1.cs

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public void Foo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Foo");
        }
    }
}
```

#### project.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

### .Net Core Console project

#### Program.cs

```
using System;
using ClassLibrary1;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    public class Program
    {
        Class1.Foo();
    }
}
```

### project.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.0"
    },
    "ClassLibrary1": "1.0.0-*"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

I can successfully add a project reference to `ClassLibrary1` in `ConsoleApplication`, this adds the reference and results in the dependency being added to my project.json in `ConsoleApplication` however when I try to use the reference eg. `ClassLibrary1.Class1.Foo();` Visual Studio fails to find the code, fails to build.

ReSharper highlights my code as Red like the question above, and does offer to add the reference, however this does nothing.

I have tried to answers in the linked question, which didn't work for me, and I'm not sure it is ReSharper with the issue as Visual Studio just won't compile the code, which doesn't have a bearing on ReSharper.

If I change the dependency and framework of my `Class1` in the `project.json` from `netstandard1.6` to `netcoreapp` as below, this does work and allows me to reference and use the class as expected in my `ConsoleApplication`. However, this seems rather hacky to me and my understanding is that `netcoreapp` is a dependency used for a runnable assembly, and `netstandard` should be the dependency for a regular class library?

Does anyone have any thoughts?

#### Hacked ClassLibrary1/project.json (Does work but seems wrong?)

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.0"
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What build error are you getting? P. S. Never mind about Resharper errors - it may still not correct work with .NET Core projects.

Comment: I know this is not exactly the answer to your problem but I had the exact same issue, in the same environment, and the only thing that fix my problem was switching to Visual Studio 2017. I'm running VS Enterprise 2017 RC.