# ReSharper not linked in EndpointConfig.cs for NServiceBus host

Tags: c#, .net, resharper, nservicebus

**Apparently**

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> does not work when viewing the `EndpointConfig.cs` file, generated by NServiceBus host.

*Neither does <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>, by the way ...*

**What I'm trying to do**

I need a reference to a `class` and `interface` that exist in different namespaces, not yet referenced previously. I would like to be able to use ReSharper.

**Symptoms**

Both the class and interface names are underlined with the red wavey line, but are not written in red:

[image]

That should be:

[image]

In any other file, that's not `EndpointConfig.cs`, ReSharper works as normal, just not in this particular file.

If I rename `EndpointConfig.cs` to something else, everything works as expected.

It's like ReSharper is hardwired to *not touch* `EndpointConfig.cs`.

> What's going on?

PS: `EndpointConfig.cs` is auto-generated when adding NServiceBus host.

Comment: Does it compile?

Comment: Compiles and runs as expected.

Comment: This is not a NSB problem it's a ReSharper problem. I have had this before. It gets confused sometimes. You should be able to clear the reference cache to fix this. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9799074/how-to-make-resharper-re-evaluate-its-assembly-reference-highlighting

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make resharper re-evaluate its assembly reference highlighting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9799074/how-to-make-resharper-re-evaluate-its-assembly-reference-highlighting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReSharper does not scan files that are shipped as part of a nuget. When you rename the file ReSharper no longer detects that it was shipped from the nuget hence it starts properly scanning that file. I do not know if it possible to change this behavior.

The best alternative I can suggest is [self hosting NServiceBus in a windows service](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/#self-hosting-windows-service-hosting). Here is a [runnable sample](https://docs.particular.net/samples/hosting/windows-service/).